# Compare performance of different database schemas

Tags: database, performance, database-design

I am trying to upgrade the performance of an existing system by changing the database schema, because I think the old schema is not so good for storing a large data.

Now I'm not sure how to point out the effects of the new schema. What metrics should I use to compare the performance of those two systems that using different schemas?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What database? Each has its own tools that can help. Can you describe the existing schema? Also, what's the ratio of read vs. write?

Comment: Did you consider buying better hardware?

Answer (score 2):

> "What metrics should I use to compare
>   the performance of those two systems
>   that using different schemas?"

Well, what metrics have lead you to the conclusion that you need to re-design the schema?

The most common cause of poor database performance is badly-written SQL.  Occasionally that is because the database schema prevents the writing of optimal queries, but usually it is because the developer didn't understand SQL or the database design well enough to write decent queries.  Shonky SQL can cause all sorts of problems; one or two bad queries, if they are called often enough, can kill an entire system.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the schema alone is not sufficient. You need to examine your indexing strategy.

The number of logical reads is a good way of determining query workload.

Run a profiling trace for a time period that represents normal activity (and activity that occurs infrequently, such as end of month reporting), capturing logical reads.